# Unable to get account listed in from drop down on Deploy Contract Screen.

Tags: blockchain, contract, geth

I am new to the blockchain. I have configured the geth and mist on my Windows 10 64bit.

I have configured the private network using command
**`"geth --datadir=./foldername/"`**

ipc file got generated and then I launched mist browser.

After launching mist I created a Main Account by following the steps.Then I tried to run a HelloWorld contract as yoseen seen in the attached image. But I am unable to see the Main Account listed in from address on Deploy Contract Screen. Due to which I think I am unable to deploy the contract.

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You need to get an initial allocated balance for at least one of your accounts. You can follow this [post](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14831) to learn how to allocate balances in the genesis.json file.

Make sure that you give it enough balance. It happened that I allocated initially "111111" and I found that in Mist UI, main window the balance for my user was "0.00"Eth. I clicked on the User account and realized that the actual balance was: "0.000000000111111", so that fooled me for a moment.

Hope it helps!